# How do I listen to click events on buttons with type submit using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several buttons with type button:

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Plain old button.</button>`

and some important buttons with type submit:

`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit button!</button>`

I want to listen to click events on buttons with type submit, but not the others.

Comment: A submit button submits a form, which reloads the page, there's no use in listening for clicks on submit buttons unless you're also preventing the form from submitting. Is this what you want, to prevent the form from submitting ?

Comment: i think this `<button type="submit"` should be `<input type="submit" or <input type="button"`

Comment: @Jai [Oh, really?](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/button)

Comment: @canon hmm....interesting i never knew about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using CSS selectors:

```
$(function() {
    $('button[type=submit]').click(function () {
        alert('Submit button clicked.');
    });
});
```

W3C provides a [CSS Selector Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/). All of which are supported by jQuery. The complete set jQuery selectors can be found at [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). Here is a complete example at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S74Rq/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(function() { 
    $('button').click(function (e) { 
        if($(this).attr('type') =='submit') {
            alert($(this).attr('type'));
        }
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/YCuuM/)